# How can i display partly-transparent pictures in Graphics.h

Tags: c++, image, sprite, bgi, winbgi

For creating a small game for a competition in class we are using **graphics.h**

I wanna make a small platformer and I need transparent backgrounds for the player sprites.

How can i accomplish this?

I am using visual studio 2015 community edition and win10.

Comment: The `<graphics.h>` header (from the 90's Turbo C++) is not included with my Visual Studio 2015. Possibly you have been given an implementation from your instructor. If it doesn't support transparency you'll just have to implement that yourself. The simplest is completely on/off transparency on a pixel by pixel basis. And for that you can use a monochrome bitmap. That's how the icons in Windows used to work.

Comment: Well i dont know if my version supports it. How can i check? It wont let me enter .png files. How can i convert them to bitmap without loosing the alpha channel?

Comment: You can use google to find partial docs, e.g. (http://www.programmingsimplified.com/c/graphics.h). That also turned up a Visual C++ implementation, (https://sourceforge.net/projects/graphicsmsvs/?source=directory). I doubt that this old library supports alpha channel bmp files, but you can possibly convert using MS Paint or e.g. Paint.NET or LView.

Comment: I got it. I converted it using Pixelformer and it works. Theres only a small border around the image but i can live with that!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `readimagefile();` to add partly-transparent gif *(or other format which allows transparency and is compatible with `readimagefile`)*.

You cannot use `getimage` or `putimage` without losing transparency.

**NOTE**: this method is slow because the code directly read the image file from the drive which slows down the code .

Answer (score 0):

If you must use `graphics.h` you need to install Turbo C/C++, which you cannot install on recent version of Windows. To install Turbo C++, you need to install [DOSBox](http://www.dosbox.com/) on Windows, and then [install Turbo C++](https://blog.windows8downloads.com/2013/02/how-to-install-and-start-turbo-c-on-windows-8-x32-x64/) inside DosBox.

If you can use Visual C++, you need to learn Windows GDI programming.

Comment: Actually i got it to work with just graphics.h and a bmp with alpha channel.

Comment: No that's not possible. You need to use GDI/GDI+, OpenGL, DirectX, .NET WinForms, OpenCV or some other library.

Comment: Well as i said in my post we are holding a competition so using anything else is cheating

Comment: @Ajay As mad as it sound they use WinBGI emulator that runs on Windows environment (no DOSBOX needed it behaves as standard win32 app) and people still doing stuff with it Especially in schools. I am all for Borland/Embarcadero and actively using it every day but **BGI** was unusable even in the **MS-DOS** days if you wanted to do some serious work in **RT** (we switched for direct **EGA/VGA/VESA** access all the time back then).